Interpretation lmer output with z-score standardized coefficients
I've been running lmer() (in the lme4 package) on my data using this formula:
fit10 <- lmer(SYMPTOM_DIFF ~ 1 + SCZ + Sex + Age + (1 | Clinic))

Giving me this output:
> summary(fit10)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: SYMPTOM_DIFF ~ 1 + SCZ + Sex + Age + (1 | Clinic)
   Data: SubMatrix

REML criterion at convergence: 170.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.3546 -0.6586 -0.0841  0.5913  5.5697 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Clinic   (Intercept) 0.002784 0.05276 
 Residual             0.062265 0.24953 
Number of obs: 1597, groups:  Clinic, 21

Fixed effects:
             Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept) -0.498937   0.031846 -15.667
SCZ          0.013272   0.006407   2.072
Sex          0.010835   0.013254   0.817
Age          0.001861   0.000685   2.717


SYMPTOM_DIFF is % change in any direction, could be + OR -.
SCZ is z-transformed, 1 unit=1 SD

My question is HOW I would interpret the estimate for SCZ here.
My first thought is that a 1 SD increase in SCZ would give a 0.013 unit change in SYMPTOM_DIFF. But since "SYMPTOM_DIFF" could be both negative and positive change, it doesn't make sense.
My second thought is that a 1 SD increase in SCZ would give 0.013 unit increase in SYMPTOM_DIFF. But looking at the data, that can't really be the case.
My third thought is that a 1 SD increase in SCZ would give 0.013 higher "change value", meaning a somewhat more positive change. Could that be the case?

"But looking at the data, that can't really be the case." Why do you think this is the case?   As the answer suggests, the model does suggest that (controlling for age and sex) a 1 SD  increase in SCZ is associated with a 0.013 unit increase in the dependent variable.

This will depend on how you standardized your data, but my understanding is that the interpretation is similar to regular OLS regression.

When only standardizing the predictor, then the coefficient represents the change in the outcome for every one standard deviation increase in your predictor.
When both predictor and outcome are standardized, then the coefficient represents the change in the outcome in standard deviations.

So in your case, if the first case is true, then SCZ shows that for every one SD increase in this predictor, you get a 0.013 increase in the outcome SYMPTOM DIFF.
